# Where can I find "cosmic" sounds like on the show Cosmos?

Tags: sound-design, audio

Where can i get sounds, musics or one OST that seem like Cosmos (the new tv show inspired in "Cosmos" by Carl Sagan)?

Comment: I have removed the part of your question that is off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sounds/music you should try out Spectrasonic's [Atmosphere](http://www.spectrasonics.net/products/legacy/atmosphere.php) or [Omnisphere](http://www.spectrasonics.net/products/omnisphere.php).
Or you can use pre-made production music. [Sonofind](http://www.sonofind.com/) is a good site to start and browse through.

Answer (score 0):

Native Instruments Absynth and Reaktor are good for this sort of Cosmic sound with some routing in your DAW and experimentation you can make one generate the other for some very interesting sounds.